# How to solve a portfolio optimization with a generalised objective function?

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio, quantitative-finance, quadprog

I have a portfolio of 5 stocks for which I want to find an optimal mix of minimizing portfolio variance and maximizing expected future dividends. The latter is from analysts forecasts. My problem is that I know how to solve an minimum variance problem but I am not sure how to put the quadratic form into the right matrix form for the objective function of quadprog.

The standard minimum variance problem reads

**`Min! ( portfolio volatility )`**

where
**`r`** has the 252 daily returns of the five stocks,
**`d`** has the expected yearly dividend yields ( where `firm_A` pays 1 **%**, `firm_B` pays 2 **%** etc, )

and I have programmed it as follows

```
dat = rep( rnorm( 10, mean = 0, sd = 1 ), 252*5 )
r   = matrix( dat, nr = 252, nc = 5 )
d   = matrix( c( 1, 2, 1, 2, 2 ) )

library(quadprog)
# Dmat (covariance) and dvec (penalized returns) are generated easily

risk.param = 0.5
Dmat = cov(r)
Dmat[is.na(Dmat)]=0

dvec = matrix(colMeans(r) * risk.param)
dvec[is.na(dvec)]=1e-5

# The weights sum up to 1
n   = 5
A   = matrix( rep( 1, n ), nr = n )
b   = 1
meq = 1

res = solve.QP( Dmat, dvec, A, b, meq = 1 )
```

Obviously, the returns in **`r`** a standard normal, hence each stocks gets about 20% weight.

**`Q1:`** How can I account for the fact that `firm_A` pays a dividend of 1, `firm_B` a dividend of 2, etc?

The new objective function reads:

**`Max! ( 0.5 * Portfolio_div - 0.5 * Portfolio_variance )`**

but I don't know how to hard-code it. The portfolio variance was easy to put into **`Dmat`** but the new objective function has the `Portfolio_div` element defined as **`Portfolio_div = w * d`** where **`w`** has the five weights.

Thanks a lot.

**`EDIT:`** Maybe it makes sense to add a higher-level description of the problem:
I am able to use a minimum-variance optimization with the code above. Minimizing the portfolio variance means optimizing the weights on the variace-covariance matrix `Dmat` (of dimension 5x5). However, I want to add an additional part to the optimization, which are the dividends in **`d`** multiplied with the weights (hence of dimension 5x1). The same weights are also used for `Dmat`.

**`Q2:`** How can I add the vector `d` to the code?

**`EDIT2:`** I guess the answer is to simply use

```
dvec = -1/d
```

as I maximize expected dividends by minimizing the inverse of the negative.

**`Q3:`** Could someone please tell me if that's right?

Answer (score 0):

### Opening a can of worms:

`TLDR` While I respect great work Harry MARKOWITZ ( 1990 Nobel prize ) has performed, I appreciate much more his wonderfull CACI Simulations spin-off deterministic simulation framework COMET III, than the Portfolio theory assumption, that **`variance` per-se** is the ruling minimiser driver for the portfolio optimisation process.

Driving this principal point of view
  <sub>*( which still may meet a bit ill-formed motivation of big funds,
that live happily from their 2-by-20 fees
due to the nature and scale of "their" **skewed perspective of perception of what are direct losses**,
which they **recognise as a non-acquired hefty & risk-free management fees**
associated with a crowd-panic churn attributed AUM erosion,
**rather than the real profits & losses**, gained from their (in)ability to deliver any above average AUM returns )*</sub> 
further,
closer to your idea
the **problem is in the proper formulation of the `{ penalty | utility }` function**.

While **`variance`** is taken in classical efficient frontier theory as a **penalty** factor, operated in a **`min!`** global search, it has not much to do with real profit generation. You get penalised even for positive-side variance components, which is a nonsense per-se.

On the contrary, the **`dividend`** is a direct benefit, an absolute **`utility`**, entering the **`max!`** optimisation process.

**So the first step in `Q3` & `Q1` ought be a design of a consistent `utility function`** isolated from relative, revenue un-related factors, but containing all other absolute factors -- a cost of entry, transaction costs, rebalancing costs -- as otherwise your utility model would be misleading your portfolio wealth management strategy.

**`A2:`** Without this a-priori designed property, no one may claim a model is worth a single CPU-hour to even start the model's global optimisation efforts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I agree that min! variance has its drawbacks (e.g. that up and down-movements are weighted equally) or shortcomings. However, I just realized today that it might maybe not make a lot of sence to max expected dividends and minimizing risk at the same time. Why? Because for normal portfolio optimization, you either decrease the risk and hold expected returns constand, or you maximize expected returns while holding risk constand at a predefined level. Would you agree that max! dividends and min! risk is a stupid concept or not? Would your utility approach allow it?

Comment: Yes, utility consists of both the dividend part and the positive-returns-side of the variance ( assumption that a variance is equal to risk is wrong, in spite of many sources re-use this anxient Markowitz simplification )